# Why isn't my js script loading in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to add a bootstrap js script to my WordPress theme the "right" way but I'm not seeing a link to the js file in the head section of the webpage when it loads. I tried adding it to the header of the WordPress theme the "right" way but no luck. Now I'm trying in the `functions.php` file and still no luck.

```
function buns_bootstrap_run(){
    wp_register_script('bootstrap-js', get_stylesheet_directory() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'),'3.2.0', false);
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap-js');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_script', 'buns_bootstrap_run');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The action isn't named `wp_enqueue_script`, but [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts)

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'buns_bootstrap_run');
```

There's a difference between the action that's called when scripts are to be enqueued, and the function that actually enqueues them

Comment: !!!!! My guy, your a freaking life saver!!! I tried everything, it's always the smallest things that causes problem's. Thanks a million! Now it's loading correctly.